# Client with IP address 'yyy.yy.yy.yy' is not allowed to access the server. My client ip is xxx.xx.xx.xx

Tags: azure, networking, ip

I am trying to login to a newly created sql server in azure.
Before connection, I am adding my client ip programmatically using azure-python sdk.
Once my client ip is added, I try to login to database.

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server 'x' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'yyy.yy.yy.yy' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect. (40615) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

This ip is different from the public ip that I get in my machine. What is the reason? I am connected to my company vpn.

I used this to retrieve my client ip - https://checkip.amazonaws.com/ - xxx.xx.xx.xx

Also, used the add client ip in azure - this gives the same result as xxx.xx.xx.xx.
[image]

**What is the ip yyy.yy.yy.yy here? How can I retrieve this so that I will be able to whitelist this programmatically?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are connecting to your Azure service via your VPN tunnel, not your primary interface; therefore you would not be presenting your public IP to the Azure service. The IP you are fetching from your checkip URL is your public IP.

You can verify this by checking the output of `route print` in a Windows terminal or simply `route` in Linux. While your VPN is active, you should see the subnet of your Azure service listed with an interface that does not match your LAN IP. Something like this:

```
       0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0        192.168.2.1     192.168.2.12     25
       172.31.0.0      255.255.0.0    10.168.0.100    10.168.44.64      1
```

In the above example, the first row shows my LAN interface as the default route (192.168.2.12) which will be used for everything (0.0.0.0); except when I'm trying to get to 172.31.0.0/16 (my "azure service", hypothetically). In which case the 10.168.44.64 interface is used, which in this case is a VPN interface.

The default interface that uses 192.168.2.12 would present my public IP to services online that do not match the VPN rule, for example, your checkip URL.

If this is the case, then you'll want to add that subnet specified by the route command for your VPN interface, or the exact IP, depending on your requirements. In this example it would be 10.168.0.100.

If you wanted to do it programmatically, then you'd have to fetch the current IP of your VPN interface.